# Error installing Cygwin in Windows

Tags: installation, window, cygwin

I want install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe), but i've this error:

```
Mostafa.R@DESKTOP-DVU9DII ~
$ cd madagascar-2.0

Mostafa.R@DESKTOP-DVU9DII ~/madagascar-2.0
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/madagascar API=c c++ f90 matlab python
checking for Python ... /usr/bin/python
checking Python version ... 2.7.14
checking for RSFROOT ... /home/madagascar
checking for SCons ... no
Installing SCons ... /home/madagascar/bin/scons
checking SCons version ... v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED]
Running RSFROOT=/home/madagascar /home/madagascar/bin/scons  config ...
------------------------
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
checking platform ... (cached) cygwin [unknown]
checking for C compiler ... (cached) gcc
checking if gcc works ... yes
checking if gcc accepts '-x c -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic' ... yes
checking for ar ... (cached) ar
checking for libraries ... no

  **Fatal missing dependency**
------------------------
Done with configuration.

Mostafa.R@DESKTOP-DVU9DII ~/madagascar-2.0
$ sfspike n1=10 out=test1 > spike.rsf
-bash: sfspike: **command not found**
```

I think, the software can not recognize libraries, because i think we have introduce the PATH to windows, but how?

Comment: Which libraries are missing?

Comment: I dont know, but when i write all commands for example "sfspike " get this error: -bash: sfspike: **command not found**

Comment: Check the docs of the program you're installing to get the dependency list. Also it may not be compatible with Cygwin as it says "unknown platform"

Comment: I'm beginner. How can i get dependency list?!

Comment: In the docs of the program, maybe a file called INSTALL

Comment: First: the title is misleading you are not installing cygwin you are compiling madagascar on cygwiin. Second: configure should produce a `config.log` look inside for the failing test. Third: no way you can install a matlab interface

Comment: See the line `checking for SCons ... no`. Use cygwin setup to install the scons package. Otherwise you may not get an scons that is patched to work in cygwin.